# Copy all files with the directory structure since the last run on remote server

Tags: ubuntu, bash, rsync, scp

I would like to scan for my `/tmp/` directory now and then and check what files have been changed since I last time did it. All files that have been changed should be copied to remote server (as a backup), perserving the directory structure. I tried something like this, but it's not quite working on Ubuntu, throwing `Permission denied (publickey).`

```
#!/bin/bash
TARGET=/bkp
HOST=ubuntu@120.120.120.120
SOURCE=/tmp

touch $TARGET/last_sync

rsync \
    -ahrv \
    --update \
    -e \
    --files-from=<ssh -i /home/ubuntu/ssh_key.pem $HOST "find $SOURCE -type f -newer $SOURCE/last_sync -exec realpath --relative-to=$SOURCE '{}' \;" \
    $HOST:$SOURCE \
    $TARGET

rsync -ahv $TARGET/last_sync $HOST:$SOURCE
```

What I had in plan is to have on a source machine:

```
ubuntu@source:~/$ tree /tmp
.
├── file1.txt
├── dir1
│   ├── subdir1
│   │   └── file3.txt
│   └── file2.txt
├── file4.txt
```

and on the first run it should be copied on a remote machine as

```
ubuntu@remote:~/$ tree /bkp
.
├── file1.txt
├── dir1
│   ├── subdir1
│   │   └── file3.txt
│   └── file2.txt
├── file4.txt
```

Several hours later, new file `/tmp/dir1/file5.txt` was added, and file `/tmp/file4.txt` was changed

After the script was executed, it should be synced (added both files) on remote:

```
ubuntu@remote:~/$ tree /bkp
.
├── file1.txt
├── dir1
│   ├── subdir1
│   │   └── file3.txt
│   └── file2.txt
|   | -- file5.txt <-- ADDED
├── file4.txt <-- ADDED (replaced)
```

I was able to achieve something similar on macos -> ubuntu, but with scp and more "logic" behind it, was checking files changed in the last N hours and running the script every N hours..

Comment: Almost by definition: `/tmp` should not hold any data that warrants making back-ups in the first place. Second: allowing rsync to discover which files it needs to copy to keep source <--> destination synchronised is usually better than trying to be smart about it with `find`. - And all of that is completely redudant to what your error is about. `Permission denied (publickey)`  is an error you get when public key authentication is not set up correctly. Debug with the ssh client set to more verbose output and check the server side sshd logs for errors/warnings.

Answer (score 0):

The primary issue seems to be that you're getting a `Permission denied (publickey)` error. This is typical of an authentication issue when using certificate-based authentication through `ssh`. Looking at your code you invoke `ssh` three times but only once do you provide a non-default private certificate (key):

1. `rsync` to perform an update
2. `ssh` to invoke `find` to look for newer files
3. `rsync` to copy a synchronisation beacon file

If `/home/ubuntu/ssh_key.pem` is the appropriate key to use for this connection, you need to reference it each time.

A secondary issue is that the syntax looks really wrong for much of your code. I know you took my recommendation on ServerFault to put the code through https://shellcheck.net/, but there are still places where the code can now be parsed by `bash` but is still syntactically wrong. For example,

> ```
> rsync \
>     -ahrv \
>     --update \
>     -e \
>     --files-from=<ssh -i /home/ubuntu/ssh_key.pem $HOST "find $SOURCE -type f -newer $SOURCE/last_sync -exec realpath --relative-to=$SOURCE '{}' \;" \
>     $HOST:$SOURCE \
>     $TARGET
> ```

If we rewrite this so that the options taking arguments are linked together, we get this:

```
rsync \
    -ahrv \
    --update \
    -e --files-from=
    -i \
    /home/ubuntu/ssh_key.pem $HOST "find $SOURCE -type f -newer $SOURCE/last_sync -exec realpath --relative-to=$SOURCE '{}' \;" $HOST:$SOURCE $TARGET
    <ssh
```

- There is no file `ssh` from which to read *stdin*, nor is there anything to process it
- The command `--files-from=` referenced by `-e` does not exist
- The four source files/directories would be copied to `$TARGET` (if the rest of the command had been valid)

I believe I can see what you're trying to achieve, but I'm not entirely sure why you don't just use `rsync` in its normal mode of operation and have it copy files directly. No need for `find`. No need for a synchronisation beacon file.

```
#!/bin/bash
rhost=ubuntu@120.120.120.120
source=/path/to/source
target=/bkp

rsync -av -e 'ssh -i /home/ubuntu/ssh_key.pem' "$rhost:$source/" "$target"
```